# Explanation of chain loading in boot loaders?

Tags: boot, bootloader

What does chain loading in boot loader mean?  I am looking for a simple explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your just asking what it is.

Chainloading is when a boot loader loads another boot loader to begin the boot process.

For example 
When using GRUB (short for GNU GRand Unified Bootloader), a boot loader package from the GNU Project with a Linux/Windows dual boot setup, with GRUB being installed on the Master Boot Record it must load the Windows Boot Loader to boot Windows.

Boots to Grub

- Boot into Linux

or

Chainload the Windows Boot Loader  / Then

- Windows Boot Loader
- Boots into Windows

More Info can be found here.

https://www.linux.com/answers/what-chainloading-and-how-do-it-do-it